# Common way to indicate non-legal value for many types without UB

Tags: c++

I'm writing some kind of (open-addressing) hash table.

For all valid types `T` that I want to allow to be contained in my hash table,
I want some non-legal value for that type to indicate that the table slot is empty.

The simplest solution I know is:

1. Let the table be `std::vector<std::optional<T>>`
2. Set that non-legal value as `std::nullopt<T>`

But I'm scared of possible overhead (because *all* entries become `std::optional` in this way). Is there any faster and at least equally safe way?

For `T`, I set the restriction as: `std::is_same_v<std::remove_cvref_t<T>, T>`. Other than this there is no restriction.

Comment: I would consider two alternate implementations: One for types which have such an in-band invalid value - which could be specified as an additional template argument or as a trait - and one for the other types.  For the other types I would consider having a bitmap associated with a bucket or group of buckets or whatever your hashtable implementation is, that bitmap to hold the present/not-present bit.  Or - you could _just_ do that and not have the one that uses the in-band invalid value at all.

Comment: @davidbak yes, ```std::vector<bool>``` can be an alternative here. I'll benchmark and compare two implementations and decide what implementation I'll choose.

Comment: `std::optional` is mandated to not do dynamic allocation.  It may take up more space.  Generically a type `T` may not have a valid sentinel value.

Comment: Or you could even be more granular than on bitmap for the entire table.  Lots of options.  Measurement is a good idea.  With open addressing assuming the jumps aren't too large your bitmap will have good locality of reference which will work nice with the CPU's caches.

Comment: @frozenca  `std::vector<bool>` is optimised to save storage, with a trade-off (adverse impact, depending on size of the vector) in terms of performance.

Comment: @Peter Yes, that's why I'm considering ```std::vector<bool>``` as an auxiliary bitmap. If it is not optimized on storage, just using a single ```std::vector<std::pair<T, bool>>``` may be a better option

Comment: Isn't std::unordered_map an option, instead of needing non-valid values, the entries in the map just will not exist. If an entry becomes invalid just remove it and it can't be looked up again. That at least would lead to code without any surprises. my experience with "special" values is that they become hard to maintain/read later on (specially by other engineers). Only do it if you have a proven performance gain that is necessary.

Comment: @PepijnKramer The implementation of ```std::unordered_map``` is based on linked lists  (the C++ standard specification forces that), so it's very slow to insert/erase. GNU ```gp_hash_table``` or ```cc_hash_table``` is based on open-addressing and has been shown to be at least several times faster than ```std::unordered_map```. I'm referring to that implementation to write my own, which should be specialized to my data.

Comment: @Peter @davidbak I've benchmarked and observed that ```std::vector<bool>``` kills performance, it was twice slower than ```std::unordered_map```. I've switched to ```std::vector<std::pair<T, bool>>``` and it was four times faster than ```std::unordered_map```. I'll go with this

Comment: @frozenca Fair point also if runtime performance is an issue then measurment is always important. But then it boils down to what is a safe unique value for an entry that is very type dependent. Maybe you can have a template function bool is_invalid_value<T>(const T& value)  and provide an specialization for the type (and you can do a compile time check if the specialization exists for your hash_table<T>). Would be nice if that function could be inlined to not have to make a call to it.

Comment: @frozenca What would be the point of `std::pair<T, bool>`? That's `std::optional`. The problem the `std::vector<bool>` solves is that alignment requirements force `std::optional` to waste a lot of space for 1 bit of information. For a mostly empty hashtable (which you want with open addressing) if also condenses that crucial bit into fewer cache lines. You probably get a lot more cache hits with `std::vector<bool>` than with `std::optional` when most searches fail (and on insert).

Comment: Instead of `std::optional` you could also use `T*` with `nullptr` as your not-there value. Replace with `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` to manage ownership.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Yes, I just found out that ```std::pair<T, bool>``` is basically ```std::optional<T>```, my bad. From the benchmark I just did, I see ```std::pair<T, bool>``` is at least eight times faster than ```std::vector<bool>```. (Tested with ```T = char, int, std::string```) Using ```std::unique_ptr<T>``` will do heap allocation for each element and kill performance even more.

Comment: @frozenca How large a table did you try? How full and what operation? There is probably a lot of variance on the speed depending on the table size in relation to cache sizes and the access pattern. The vector will shine if you have a lot of lookups returning not-found. Otherwise it trades space for time. A `std::unique_ptr<T>` will only be beneficial if `T` is large and copying it into the table is expensive. char, int and even std::string are tiny. `shared_ptr` will shine when you want to return references to the stored objects and not have to worry about their lifetimes.

Comment: @frozenca Having a bunch of specializations might be necessary if you want optimal results.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow The tested sizes were: ```n = 1000, 10000, 100000```. Max load factor is 2/3. Generated n random elements (duplication allowed). Inserted them in random order. Retrieved them in random order. Erased them in random order. If all retrievals/removals are successful, correctness is verified. Repeated this for 500~1000 times and averaged them to measure time. In all test case variants ```std::vector<bool>``` was very very slow. I think it's mainly because its complicated reference proxy class.

Comment: @frozenca The reference proxy should optimize away. Given that access pattern I would expect some slowdown. inserts and successful retrieval mean you first have to access the vector and then always have to access the value too, which will be 2 cachelines. With `std::optional<char>` both the present bit and the value will be next to each other and I could imagine the compiler generates single 16bit read/write access for it. You should also test far larger tables. 100000 might still fit in L1 cache and certainly in L2. Does your table resize when needed? That changes things too.

Comment: `std::vector<bool>` is not an optimal bitmap.  Iterators must return a _reference_ to a _bit_, which requires proxy iterators: slow! And that includes bit access with `operator[]` which returns such an iterator as its value.  (This is a well known flaw of the C++ standard prescribed specialization of `std::<vector>` for `bool`'; various proposals have been made, over time, to depreciate the specialization and provide an alternative bitset structure.) Takeaway: Don't use `std::vector<bool>` or be disappointed, roll your own (dynamic) bitset or consider `boost::dynamic_bitset`.

Comment: A problem with, say, a pair of bool + `T` is that for most purposes that pair will have to be padded for alignment purposes (either in itself or between elements of an array of them) and that will increase your overall data structure size and decrease how much of it (in particular, how many hash slots) can fit in a cache line (or two).  Take a look at your data structure _layout_ and see how it affects you.

Comment: People are currently working on proposals to the C++ standard!  See for example [p2158 - Deprecate std::vector<bool>, promote std::tr2::dynamic_bitset and map a timeline for C++23](https://github.com/ThePhD/future_cxx/issues/13) (though sadly I see the author just 4 days ago bumped up the projected milestone from C++23 to C++ ... _29_ ...)

Comment: @frozenca I am working on [`tiny::optional`](https://github.com/Sedeniono/tiny-optional) for a while now. It aims to be a drop-in replacement (as far as possible) for `std::optional` while exploiting platform specific unused bit patterns to encode the empty state. I.e., `tiny::optional<bool>`, `tiny::optional<double>` and `tiny::optional<T*>` have the size of `bool`, `double` and `T*`, respectively. Custom sentinels are also possible. It probably still has some kinks, but it seems to work pretty well already. I'd be interested to know if the concept would be of help here. :-)